# Getting A Connection String From An Existing Connection

Tags: oracle, connection-string, sqlplus

I have an Oracle database installed on my computer, and I can connect to it with both Oracle Developer and SQL*Plus. Using either of these tools, is there any way to determine the connection string used for the existing connection?

Answer (score 1):

In sql*plus, it stores the safe things (not the password) in `_USER`, `_CONNECT_IDENTIFIER` and `_PRIVILEGE` defined variables. By default, you can access them like:

```
prompt &_USER.@&_CONNECT_IDENTIFIER &_PRIVILEGE
```

Comment: This doesn't actually produce a connection string. It relates some of the information _used_ in a connection string, but not the entire thing.

Comment: This produces connection strings fine for me. What are you missing? (other than the password, which would obviously not be available, at least in plain text)

Comment: Cool, didn't know that.